# GCP Workflow : Can we setup a step wait for other steps to complete?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am using GCP Workflow Beta to check if I can build some of my workflows. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/sample-workflows#step_order) mentions how we can conditionally execute steps with `switch case` and `next` for jumps. However can we have a flows where

1. A step waits for two or more previous steps to complete
2. Multiple steps triggered the same time.

As you can see, what I am implying is conditional parallel execution of steps. Is there a way to do this ?

Also, I see we have some basic functions like `len`, `string` etc in the examples. Can you please guide me where I can find a list of all such functions that are available ? I was looking for something to manipulate JSON.

Comment: If you have requests for specific functions, please add them to the public issue tracker: https://b.corp.google.com/issues?q=componentid:976157

Comment: @KrisBraun the link asks for a user name and password

Comment: @vzurd this is the right url - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:976157  (b.corp.google.com is an internal one), we'll have to login with a Google account though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't wait a step because you can't run multiple step in parallel for now.

In my company, we also expect, and wait, a lot about parallelization and that's why I had a meeting with the PM yesterday to share these expectation with him. It's one of the top priority in the roadmap but I don't know when it will be released (something like Q1 or Q2 2021 I guess).

The functions sounds like python code but it's not really clear in the documentation. I will share this with the PM.

Comment: The functions description and the list of available functions are already in the roadmap (sounds obvious but confirmed). No ETA but stay tuned!

Comment: Is there any update on this topic? Do GCP Workflows support parallel step execution now? I can't find any documentation to set it up.

Comment: Still in private preview. nothing public for now.

Comment: Parallel steps are now supported, and we've found it to be very useful.  https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/parallel-steps